# Não consigo atualizar uma referência

Tags: c#

Tenho um projeto MVC. Na solution estão pendurados alguns projetos auxiliares. Bem, o que acontece que adicionei algumas referências e quando eu starto o projeto me dá erro dizendo que um projeto possui uma referência mais atualizada que o outro. Porém, coloquei as duas versões iguais e continua. Como eu resolvo isso? Está assim. Um projeto chamado Infrastructure.Data, possui a mesma versão de System.Web.MVC(4.0.0.1). O projeto Infrastructure, em realidade não precisa dessa referência, porém se eu remover, me dá vários "paus", então preferi deixar, mas continua dando erro. Abaixo o erro:

> Error 1   Assembly 'Operador.Infrastructure.Data, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'     uses 'System.Web.Mvc,
>   Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' 
>     which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>     c:\Projetos_MVC\Operador.Infrastructure.Data\bin\Debug\Operador.Infrastructure.Data.dll 
>         Operador.MVC

O que eu acho estranho é que na tentativa de arrumar o problema, me apareceu esse e estava tudo funcionando, e não sei o que está acontecendo:

> Error 1   The type 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext' is defined in an
>   assembly that is not referenced.      You must add a reference to
>   assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. 
>     C:\Projetos_MVC\Operador.MVC\BrandContextFacade.cs  17  18
>     Operador.MVC

Answer (score 1):

No próprio erro está dizendo que a `versão 4.0.0.1` do `Operador.Infrastructure.Data` é maior que `System.Web.Mvc 4.0.0.0.` Você só pode ter uma dessas referencias no seu projeto.

Realmente os projetos que complementa a solução principal não precisam ter o `System.Web.Mvc`, sendo pertinente somente no projeto **Mvc Web**. Remova essa referencia e tente arrumar os erros que estão dando, além do mais não é boa prática usar algo que não precisa !!!

Comment: Então, acontece que eu adicionei a mesma referência em ambos os projetos e não sei porque está dando essa inconsistência de versão.

Comment: Em realidade tudo estava preso no assembly do Entity. Eu removi tudo e reinstalei e isso resolveu. Ele dava uma mensagem, mas o core do problema estava no entity. Pelo NuGet atualizei tudo e agora está fine.

Comment: Não é problema veja bem, é que chocou versionamentos entre os diversos outros pacotes instalados, mas, também reforçando você não precisa ter o `System.Web.Mvc` em todos os projetos ... Bom estou apenas lhe alertando ...

Answer (score 1):

E o mesmo caso de outra pergunta aqui do SO, então seja essa resposta sobre ter [problemas ao atualizar NuGet Packages](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168927/3825).

Isso ocorre quando a versão de uma dependencia no qual foi compilada o pacote NuGet é diferente da versão de no projeto em que se está tentando instalar.

O problema maior é que o proprietário do pacote Nuget não deve ter especificado qual é versão do `System.Web.Mvc` o pacote NuGet depende. E acabamos recebendo esse error super incoveniente.

O que vc pode fazer para tentar atualziar todas as DLLs do `System.Web.Mvc` para a versão `4.0.0.1` e ver se dará certo. Tente instalar [essa versão do Microsoft AspNet MVC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/4.0.40804) ou anterior. Não sei exatamente qual irá fornecer a DLLs na versão 4.0.0.1 (Importante não confundir a versão do pacote NuGet com a versão da DLL. Um pacote NuGet pode contar várias DLLs com diversas versões).