# Problema de instalar novo Nuget Pack

Tags: visual-studio, pdf, nuget

Eu tento baixar PDF.js via Nuget, porém dá problema:

Erro: `Could not install package 'PDF.js 1.3.91'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.`

Estou usando Visual Studio do ano 2015.

Alguém já passou por isso ? E como resolver ?

Answer (score 0):

Isso ocorre quando a versão do .NET Framework no qual foi compilada o pacote NuGet é diferente da versão do projeto em que se está tentando instalar.

O problema maior é que o proprietário do pacote Nuget não especificou qual é versão do .NET Framework o pacote NuGet depende. E acabamos recebendo esse error super incoveniente.

No caso desse pacote em específico, para piorar, o link para o site do projeto é *fake*. Então sequer podemos ir no site oficial do componentar para conferir a versão compilada.

O que vc pode fazer para tentar rodar é mudar a versão do .NET Framrwork que irá compilar seu projeto, até encontrar uma que a instalação funcione.

No site do pacote NuGet tem um link "Contact Owners". Vc também pode mandar uma mensagem para eles perguntando pela versão e pedindo para adicionarem a versão do .NET Framework como dependencia.

Comment: Oi @Thiago Lunardi, eu corro risco de mudar a versão de NET Framrwork ?

Comment: Se quiser usar o pacote PDF.js, sim. Ter'a que mudar, pois esse nao suporta a versao v4.5.2.